# Can not make my lightbox2 work on IE 8 and 7

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I am trying to make my lightbox work in IE 7-8, they work fine in 9 above but for some reason they do not want to work in IE 8 and 7. This is the same for the popups in the navigation.

http://madaxedesign.co.uk/dev/portfolio.html

Lightbox I used. 
http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/

It seems to work fine on this link above but when I implement it into my website it breaks, could this be because of the bundle I have made? I was wondering if anyone can understand why this might be?

If you need to see the code please ask.

Thanks

Comment: http://lokeshdhakar.com/forums/index.php?p=/discussion/5486/lightbox-doesn039t-work-in-internet-explorer-8

Comment: I see so there isn't a fix but finding a lightbox that works with HTML5? That is a bugger

Comment: I've been using shadowbox for a long time and it hasn't treated me wrong yet - http://www.shadowbox-js.com

Comment: Yeah I went over to use one called html5lightbox worked perfectly. Just an annoying issue that can be fixed without using Rel="" but using classes instead.

Answer (score 0):

http://html5box.com/html5lightbox/

I changed the lightbox to one that supported HTML5 which is the link above.

I also found out you can make the lightbox 2 work if you change the REL="" to CLASS="" which is better explained here: 
https://www.creativewhim.com/6-html5-validation-errors-and-how-to-fix-them/#comment-10954

Althought I couldn't get this to work so resolved it using the html5box.

Thanks for your help guys